# Angularjs selectall using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I am new to Angularjs. I have some legacy code with me. I want to select all checkboxes once parent checkbox is selected.
Below is my parent checkbox.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="test" class="col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="col-xs-1" checked>
</div>
```

if someone checks this one all the remaining checkboxes should be checked.Below is my child checkbox

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName" class="col-xs-3 control-label">First Name</label>
    <input id="{{fields[0].name}}" type="checkbox" value="{{fields[0].name}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(fields[0].name) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(fields[0].name)" class="col-xs-1" />
    <div ng-class="{'col-xs-4':test && !tableView, 'col-xs-8':!isAvailable || test && tableView, 'review-column': true, even: true}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" ng-model="data.name.firstName" focus="" value="{{data.name.firstName}}"></input>
</div>
```

I tried many suggestions but nothing seems to work. Can some one point one the correct html to do so along with controller js code..Many thanks

Comment: use the same ng-model for all of them

Comment: or use an ng-model for parent checkbox and then ng-check for other checkboxes with that ng-model

Comment: follow this link http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-checked

Comment: Can u give some code examples..Like I mentioned I am new to this...

Comment: @coder310 open this link http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-checked

Comment: @hasibur - I was able to get it to work using your example...but now suppose if checkbox is checked, I need to create a list and pass on the json to spring controller...any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @coder310, 'hashibur' solution is good, but of you check all the below checkboxes the select all check box will not get checked. for that you have to use a directive. pls check my answer once.

Comment: Ok Let me check...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Custom directive to achieve your `select_all check-box feature`.

Here is an example to achieve it.

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
        isSelected: true,
        desc: "One"
    }, {
        isSelected: false,
        desc: "Two"
    }, {
        isSelected: false,
        desc: "Three"
    }];
});

app.directive('checkboxAll', function () {
  return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    var parts = iAttrs.checkboxAll.split('.');
    iElement.attr('type','checkbox');
    iElement.bind('change', function (evt) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        var setValue = iElement.prop('checked');
        angular.forEach(scope.$eval(parts[0]), function (v) {
          v[parts[1]] = setValue;
        });
      });
    });
    scope.$watch(parts[0], function (newVal) {
      var hasTrue, hasFalse;
      angular.forEach(newVal, function (v) {
        if (v[parts[1]]) {
          hasTrue = true;
        } else {
          hasFalse = true;
        }
      });
      if (hasTrue && hasFalse) {
        iElement.attr('checked', false);
        iElement.addClass('greyed');
      } else {
        iElement.attr('checked', hasTrue);
        iElement.removeClass('greyed');
      }
    }, true);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <input checkbox-all="list.isSelected" /> Select All
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="elem in list">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="elem.isSelected" /> {{elem.desc}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Please run this code**

[HEre is the plunker of the code](https://plnkr.co/edit/ILbLUvo5JqatV5YgErPe?p=preview)

Comment: @coder310, pls implement the same, just change your data, as I didn't have your data, I created example code.pls run the code and also check the plunker link I have given.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="test" class="col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="col-xs-1" ng-model="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName" class="col-xs-3 control-label">First Name</label>
    <input id="{{fields[0].name}}" type="checkbox" value="{{fields[0].name}}" ng-checked="checkbox" class="col-xs-1" />
    <div ng-class="{'col-xs-4':test && !tableView, 'col-xs-8':!isAvailable || test && tableView, 'review-column': true, even: true}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" ng-model="data.name.firstName" focus="" value="{{data.name.firstName}}"></input>
</div>
```